# Derivative of $e^y=x^{\ln x}$?

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

How to obtain $y'$ from $e^{y}=x^{\ln x}$?

This is what I did:
$$\ln e^y = \ln x^{\ln x}$$
$$y = \ln ^2 x$$
$$y' = \frac{2 \ln x}{x}$$
Is this correct? When I compare it with an online derivative calculator, the result they gave was different, and they used implicit differentiation instead.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Graphs look good too.

Comment: I'd avoid $\ln^2x$, which is ambiguous, preferring $(\ln x)^2$; this said, you did perfectly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we use implicit differentiation:

$$e^{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=2\ln(x)x^{\ln(x)-1}$$

But $e^{y} = x^{\ln(x)}$, so:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=2\ln(x) \frac{x^{\ln(x)-1}}{x^{\ln(x)}}=\frac{2\ln(x)}{x}$$

So you are quite right in your answer (and your approach is absolutely fine too!)

Answer (score 2):

$$(e^y)'=e^yy'$$ and $$(e^{ln^2x})'=(\ln^2x)'e^{ln^2x}=2\frac{\ln x}xe^{ln^2x}.$$

Then dividing by $e^y=e^{ln^2x}$,

$$y'=2\frac{\ln x}x.$$

As expected, same answer, though a little more tedious.

---

This is
$$g(y)=f(x),\\
g'(y)y'=f'(x),\\
y'=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(y)}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(g^{-1}(f(x)))}$$
versus
$$y=g^{-1}(f(x)),\\
y'=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(g^{-1}(f(x)))}
$$
by the formula for the inverse function and the chain rule.